# Data vs Centroid Agreement in skfuzzy C-Mean

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
data.shape
#(6741, 6)
centroid.shape
#(10, 6)
cntr, u, u0, d, jm, p, fpc = fuzz.cluster.cmeans(data.T, 10, 2, `error=0.00005, maxiter=100,init = centroid)`
```

Error:

> shapes (10,6) and (6741,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 6741 (dim 0)

If I transpose centroid

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,10) (10,10)
>   (6,10)

No. of data points = 6741. Features = 6. Classes = 10
So centroid should be (10,6) dimensions right? Why is it expecting 6741?

Comment: In the desription it is said `init : 2d array, size (S, N); N is the number of data sets; S is the number of features within each sample vector.`

Comment: `u0` is the centroid matrix, you can run cmeans on your data without initialization and inspect it to understand the format algorithm expects